# Recognizing Mathematical Equations using Matlab's OCR

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr

I'm trying to use Matlab's ocr to recognize math equations but the result was some unknown characters. This is my input:

[image: input]

and the output was:

[image: this]

How can I improve or solve this problem? I just followed the code on the ocr documentaions and use the `MathEquations`. Here is the code that I used:

```
x = imread('1.png');
results = ocr(x,'Language', 'MathEquation')
recognized = results.Text;
figure;
imshow(x);
text(600,150, recognized,'BackgroundColor', [1 1 1]);
```